# How to get specific Document ID from Firebase Firestore where there the ID is randomly generated and does not have a unique identifier?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Evening guys, I am working on my Final Year Project using `Firebase Firestore`. Everything is working smoothly until now, when creating the User document I used the `document(uid)`, but in the request document that I created, as seen below

[image]

The `documentID` is randomly generated, because the user can make multiple requests, so the `documentID` cannot be the same `UID`. Now I am stuck at a point where the user receives the request, and wishes to accept/decline. I am using this code:

```
let TrashAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Decline", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
                
                let dbCollection = K.FStore.db.collection(K.FStore.RequestTransmission.collectionName).document("RDvjapleBC7TBBQ15NE9")
                    dbCollection.updateData([
                        K.FStore.RequestTransmission.isDeclined : true
                    ]){ err in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                            
                        } else {
                            print("Document successfully updated")
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
                success(true)
            })
            TrashAction.backgroundColor = .red
```

I want to replace the hardcoded `DocumentID`, here: `K.FStore.db.collection(K.FStore.RequestTransmission.collectionName).document("RDvjapleBC7TBBQ15NE9")`

How to do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: There must be a unique identifier.... at least the email of sender or something you can use ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thats what driving me crazy, the user might have multiple requests, how to pick what document?

Comment: Is the `sender` the user's email?

Comment: Yes, but the User (sender) can donate more than once

Comment: Just to clarify, let's say my email is `test@domain.tld`, you need all documents with sender as `test@domain.tld`. Am I right ?

Comment: Correct, there are multiple documents with sender as `test@domain.tld`, I need ONE of them.

Comment: I've added an answer. If helpful you can accept/upvote so others know it's resolved else feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: I know there's an accepted answer, and it's not bad, but there is another option. That answer relies on a senders & receivers email address so the user has to keep issuing a query to see if there's any data returned; and what happens if the email address changes? The app breaks, right? So what you want to do is include the sender & receiver UID in the document because those don't change. Then, add a listener for any added documents that match the receivers uid. As documents are added, the receiver will be automatically notified (instead of clicking over and over).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get documents and you know value of a field in the document, you can use queries.

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
let collectionRef = db.collection("collectionName")

// Create a query against the collection.
let query = collectionRef.whereField("sender", isEqualTo: "test@domain.tld")
                .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
                .limit(to: 1)

query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
```

That should print IDs of all documents matching your query.

You can additionally use `.limit(to: 2)` to limit number of documents to be returned.

Comment: Is there a way to get the last one? will limiting it to 1 return the last one?

Comment: @mohamad I have updated the answer, please try that query. Using the `.orderBy()` you first order it by timestamp in descending order and then limit to 1.